# my weekly visit(s) here

Tags: grammar

> It feels like my weekly visit(s) here is/are more like an
> inconvenience to you than anything else.

Would both "visit" and "visits" mean that *I* visit the other person once a week?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use either "visit" or "visits" to describe the regular visiting. However, the second "like" is a bit unusual. I would replace it with "of":

> It feels like my weekly visit here is more of an inconvenience to you than anything else.

> It feels like my weekly visits here are more of an inconvenience to you than anything else.

EDIT:

Another person suggested that visiting several times every week could be described as "weekly visits". I would not describe them that way. For example, if you visited Sunday through Friday every week (missing only Saturday), then I would call those visits "six times per week" or "nearly daily" but not "weekly". I speak Northeast U.S. English.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is NO.

They don't necessarily mean the same thing.

Your weekly visit indicate that you visit once a week.

Your weekly visits is an ambiguous phrase.

It might refer to once or a week or to two or more times a week, possibly Wednesdays one week and Mondays and Fridays the next.

All that is certain is that you visit each week.